# How to don't close window in c# wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I try do when something is running then you cannot close app. 
So in MainWindow class i write override method.

```cs
        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            //something
            if (vm._isRun)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            base.OnClosing(e);
        }
```

But when isRun is true and I try close app, app is closing.

Comment: Did you set breakpoint on if and check state of vm._isRun?

Comment: @LouisGo yes, this if is working

Comment: For "it doesn't work" questions, [mcve] really helps.

Comment: And what happens if you put `base.OnClosing(e);` in `else` clause? Thus call `base.OnClosing(e);` only if you want to close the app (i.e. `vm._isRun` is false)?

Comment: What command do you use to close the app?

Comment: @Dante, glad to hear that.